# Get all collections from one device in SCCM

Tags: c#, sccm

I am currently writing a small program to interact with SCCM and query device collections. But because I am using Asp.Net 5 it seems that the SCCM dlls' AdminUI.WqlQueryEngine and Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider are incompatible because when I tried to connect:

```
//' Connect to SMS Provider
                SmsNamedValuesDictionary namedValues = new SmsNamedValuesDictionary();
                WqlConnectionManager connection = new WqlConnectionManager(namedValues);
                connection.Connect(serverName);
```

I received following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

My work around so far is just using WMI:

```
public static List<CollectionSccmCM> GetCMDeviceCollections(string hostname, string siteCode, string siteServer= null){

        List<CollectionSccmCM> collectionList = new List<CollectionSccmCM>();

        try{
            string Namespace;

            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(siteServer)){
                Namespace = @"Root\SMS\Site_" + siteCode;
            } else {
                Namespace = (@"\\" + siteServer + @"\root\SMS\Site_" + siteCode);
            }
            
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(Namespace);

            scope.Connect();

            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(String.Format("SELECT SMS_Collection.Name, SMS_Collection.CollectionID, SMS_Collection.CollectionType FROM SMS_FullCollectionMembership, SMS_Collection where name = '{0}' and SMS_FullCollectionMembership.CollectionID = SMS_Collection.CollectionID", hostname));

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

            if (queryCollection != null)
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in queryCollection)
                {
                    CollectionSccmCM coll = new CollectionSccmCM()
                        {
                            Name = obj["Name"].ToString(),
                            CollectionID = obj["CollectionID"].ToString()
                        };
                        collectionList.Add(coll);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException ex)
        {
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)){
                EventService.WriteEventLog(String.Format("Unathorized access exception thrown: {0}", ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)){
                EventService.WriteEventLog(String.Format("Unhandled expection thrown: {0}", ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }

        return collectionList;

    }
```

Anyways, someone experienced a similar problem when using these dlls'? or is it the best way just to use ManagementObjectSearcher ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late now, but if you *have* to get this to work with the `WqlConnectionManager` you can edit your projects csproj and change the `TargetFramework` to `net5.0-windows` and include the tag `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
  <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will include windows forms into your application, so you need to decide if this is worth it. I think, the correct way should be using WMI like the parent question. But rewriting might not be an option.